# How to recursively uncompress gz files on a remote host with limited commands?

Tags: ssh, remote, gzip

I have a bunch of `.jpg.gz` files in a directory that I need to decompress.

I know that the decompress command is:

`tar -xzvf FileNameHere.jpg.gz`

But is there a flag that you can recursively uncompressed the files in a directory? I have over a hundred compressed files and I don't want to manually decompress every single one.

Also since I am SSHing into an hosting service I only have the following commands to use:

```
arch
bzip2
cal
cksum
cmp
cp
crontab
basename
cd
chmod
ls
date
df
du
dos2unix
unix2dos
file
getfacl
gzip
head
hostid
tail
mkdir
mv
nslookup
sdiff
tar
uptime
wget
whois
unzip
```

Comment: `tar` is used to create or unpack archives.  An archive is a collection of several files, and may also contain a directory-structure.  Often archives are compressed - usually with `gzip` (.tar.gz), `bzip2` (.tar.bz2) or `xz`(.tar.xz) - but the compression/uncompression is done with separate programs... `tar` however, can call these programs seamlessly (when given the z, j, or J option).  Your files are *not* tar-archives, but `gzip`ed files - to uncompress, simply use `gunzip` (or `gzip -d`.  JPG is a compressed format, so it's usually redundant to compress it again.

Comment: When you say *SSHing into an hosting service* do you mean you do not have an interactive shell, but rather can only just do ssh foo@host <comand>?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To extract your files, you need to use `gzip`:

```
gzip -d *.jpg.gz
```

You mention doing this recursively; given that you don't have `find`, you'll have to visit each directory in turn and run the above command.

Comment: Does anyone know if it makes a difference if the files have the extension .jpg.gz?

Comment: Really sorry about that, but I only saw that extension now. Also I should make it known that I am using an SSH terminal on a hosting service and can't use gunzip

Comment: And Stephen added the `-d` parm to gzip to decompress the file

Answer (score 8):

If shell of the host you are `ssh`ing to is bash version >= 4.0, you can [enable the globstar option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#index-shopt).  When enabled, the `**` glob will recursively match subdirectories.  So the following should do what you need:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for gz_file in **/*.jpg.gz; do
    gzip -d "$gz_file"
done
```

No manual recursing into subdirectories required.

Answer (score 3):

While a shell script could be written to recurse the directories (but I don't think you have access to a remote sh), you could use this crude but effective shortcut, assuming your remote restricted ssh does wildcard expansion:

```
gzip -d *.jpg.gz
gzip -d */*.jpg.gz
gzip -d */*/*.jpg.gz
...
```

...depending on the depth and size of the subdirectories.

Note: If you have too many files, you can end up exceeding the [command line length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit)

edit: This used to include an answer using ls -R, but that doesn't provide full paths.

Comment: As written, the grep and cat run locally, so the entire `ls` output has to go over the network to be filtered by a local `grep`.

Comment: Correct.  Note that the OP doesn't have a remote grep.

Comment: ah, of course.  It's worth considering a shell loop on the remote side for the text processing.  `ls -R | IFS= while read fn; do [ "x$fn" = "x*.gz" ] && gzip -d "$fn";done`.  If I got that right, it should work with POSIX sh, no bash required.  It also handles anything except `\n` in filenames.  I forget if glob matching works that way; you might have to check for a trailing .gz with `[ "x${fn%.gz}" != "x$fn" ]` or something.

Comment: You will notice that the OP doesn't have a shell in the list of available commands - I wasn't sure if that means restricted ssh that doesn't start off with a shell, but rather just an `execve()` of the command given on the ssh command line.

Comment: Good point.  I don't have experience with restricted shell environments like that either.  However, the accepted answer uses a glob expression, which wouldn't work if `ssh` wasn't invoking a shell at some point.  Still, an answer like this appears to be the best you can do for environments where there is no shell at all.  `ssh -C` (to use gzip-compression) will be worth using in this case, where some redundant bulk text has to go over the wire.

Comment: You can improve your commands to work on filenames containing anything but newlines:  `( IFS=$'\n'; ssh foo@bar gzip -d $(< /tmp/jpgs.txt) )`, or `xargs </tmp/jpgs.txt -d'\n' ssh foo@bar gzip -d`.  I also eliminated the unnecessary invocations of `cat`.  The non-xargs version uses a subshell to avoid altering IFS in the current shell.

Comment: Did this work for anyone? Every `ls -R` (with nontty stdout) I've seen puts the directorypath on one line and the contained filenames (only) on subsequent lines, so I need to **recombine** with something like `ls -R | awk '/:$/{dir=substr($0,1,length()-1)} /[.]jpg[.]gz$/{print dir $0}' >pathnamesforgzipd` Alternatively select only the dirnames and add `/*.jpg.gz` and let those be globbed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You're absolutely right and I forget occasionally `ls -R` != `find .`   I think I'll remove it from my answer -- if you like, create an answer with the awk.